# Vertical alignment of Buttons text in Safari browser

Tags: html, css, safari, cross-browser, shopify

I am working on a Shopify website, buttons text vertical alignment is all good in Chrome , firefox and IE browsers, but not in Safari browser. This is my website and password is "geforce950"

[Click here to see my site](https://artisanvalley.eu/)

I have tried vertical-align: middle but it did not work.

For example: Home page slider button "Shop Now" css code:

```
.section--slideshow .slider .slide .caption a.button{ 
    background:#7db547;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: 'Arial MT Std';
    font-size:15px;
    padding: 0 15px; 
    line-height: 45px;
```

}

Any best practice to align text in vertically middle of buttons or code for Safari browser?

Comment: Could you post code here that minimally reproduces the problem? Your site might change and then the question will be useless for future visitors

Comment: I have edited the code, example of the code when it had issues, i have wrote a separate CSS for Safari browsers, seems all good now.

Comment: Can you post your solution, please? It's totally legitimate to post/accept your own answer if you figure something out.